# How do you build a Nest SearchRequest object and see the raw JSON in query?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Nest 6.2 with ES 6.6

I have the following code which runs fine:

```cs
var response = elasticClient.Search<PropertyRecord>(s => s
    .Query(q => q.Terms(
        c => c
            .Field(f => f.property_id_orig)
            .Terms(listOfPropertyIds) // a list of 20 ids say... 
    ))
    .From(0)
    .Take(100) // just pull up to a 100... 
);

if (!response.IsValid)
    throw new Exception(response.ServerError.Error.Reason);

return response.Documents;
```

But I know there is an issue with the underlying query, because all documents from the index are returned.  So I would like to be able to see the raw Json that is generated by the lambda expression so I can see the result running in the Head plugin or Fiddler etc.

If I use a SearchRequest Object and pass that to the Search method, would I then be able to see the Query Json?

```cs
var request = new SearchRequest
{
    // and build equivalent query here
};
```

I am having trouble building the corresponding query using the SearchRequest approach and cannot find decent examples showing how to do so.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the JSON for *any* NEST request using [`SerializeToString` extension method](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/6.x/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Serialization/IElasticsearchSerializer.cs#L38-L41)

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

var listOfPropertyIds = new [] { 1, 2, 3 };

// pull the descriptor out of the client API call
var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<PropertyRecord>()
    .Query(q => q.Terms(
        c => c
            .Field(f => f.property_id_orig)
            .Terms(listOfPropertyIds) // a list of 20 ids say... 
    ))
    .From(0)
    .Take(100);

var json = client.RequestResponseSerializer.SerializeToString(searchDescriptor, SerializationFormatting.Indented);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

which yields

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "property_id_orig": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 100
}
```